# Deriving a toy model for a particle in a potential interacting with a neutral scalar field

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory

In section 6.2 of Folland's *Quantum Field Theory*, he constructs a toy model for a particle of mass $M$ moving in a potential $V$ interacting with a neutral scalar field. Here he takes space to be contained within a box of side length $L$. He considers a Hamiltonian $H$ of the form
$$H = H_p + H_f + H_I$$
where $H_p$ is the Hamiltonian of the particle of mass $M$, $H_f$ is the Hamiltonian of the field, and $H_I$ the Hamiltonian of the interaction with coupling constant $g$.

More specifically, he considers an eigenvalue $E_n$ of $H_p$, which he says is also an eigenvalue of $$H_0 = H_p + H_f$$
with eigenvector $|n\rangle$, the state where the particle has energy $E_n$ and there is no field quanta present. The goal of this part of the section is to determine how the presence of the field affects $E_n$ to second order in $g$.

I've omitted many of the details, but he shows that with cutoff $K$:
$$\Delta E_n = -\frac{g^2}{2L^3} \sum_{|\textbf{p}| \leq K}\frac{1}{\omega_p} \langle n; \textbf{p} | e^{i\textbf{p} \cdot \textbf{x}}(H_0 - E_n)^{-1}e^{-i\textbf{p} \cdot \textbf{x}} | n; \textbf{p} \rangle. \tag{1}$$

He then shows that $$e^{i\textbf{p} \cdot \textbf{x}}(H_0 - E_n)^{-1}e^{-i\textbf{p} \cdot \textbf{x}} = \Big(H_0 - E_n + \frac{|\textbf{p}|^2}{2M} - \frac{\textbf{p}\cdot\nabla}{M}\Big)^{-1} \tag{2}$$
by using the identity
$$e^{i\textbf{p}\cdot \textbf{x}} \circ \nabla \circ e^{-i\textbf{p}\cdot \textbf{x}} = \nabla - \textbf{p} \tag{3}$$

He then uses (2) in (1) to obtain:
$$\Delta E_n = -\frac{g^2}{2L^3} \sum_{|\textbf{p}| \leq K}\frac{1}{\omega_p} \Big\langle n; \textbf{p} \Big| \Big(\omega_p + \frac{|\textbf{p}|^2}{2M} - \frac{\textbf{p}\cdot\nabla}{M} \Big)^{-1}\Big| n; \textbf{p} \Big\rangle. \tag{4}$$

---

I have two questions about the above.

1. If apply the left-hand side of (3) to a test function $f$, I get
   $$(e^{i\textbf{p}\cdot \textbf{x}} \circ \nabla \circ e^{-i\textbf{p}\cdot \textbf{x}})f = e^{i\textbf{p}\cdot \textbf{x}}\nabla(e^{-i\textbf{p}\cdot \textbf{x}}f) = e^{i\textbf{p}\cdot \textbf{x}}\big[-i\textbf{p}e^{-i\textbf{p}\cdot \textbf{x}}f + e^{-i\textbf{p}\cdot \textbf{x}}\nabla f\big] = -i\textbf{p}f + \nabla f$$
   and hence
   $$e^{i\textbf{p}\cdot \textbf{x}} \circ \nabla \circ e^{-i\textbf{p}\cdot \textbf{x}} = \nabla - i\textbf{p}.$$

Have I made a mistake in my derivation?

2. I am unclear on how $\omega_p$ appears in (4). Comparing the operators in (2) and (4), it seems that
   $$H_0 - E_n = \omega_p.$$
   If so, where does this equality come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the first question, you are correct. It seems to be a typo in your edition of the book. In the version of the book I am looking at, the "i" is there.

Regarding the second question, $H_0 - E_n = \omega_{\mathbf p}$ is not correct in general. However, the state is acting on $|n;\mathbf p\rangle$ and
$$ H_0 |n;\mathbf p\rangle = (H_p \otimes 1 + 1 \otimes H_f) |n;\mathbf p\rangle = (E_n + \hbar\omega_{\mathbf p}) |n;\mathbf p\rangle $$
since $|\mathbf p\rangle$ is an eigenstate of $H_f$.

Comment: Thank you! I must have missed something fundamental when reading the book, but how do we know that $|\textbf{p}\rangle$ is an eigenstate of $H_f$ with eigenvalue $\hbar \omega_p$?

Comment: @CBBAM In my version of the book, that is equation (6.15).

Comment: I see it now, thank you for all your help.